# Trying to install OS to new computer; Won't detect HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, motherboard, sata

Mobo: Biostar th67+

CPU: i3 2100

GPU: Radeon 6850 (using integrated right now)

PSU: Antec 400 Watts

HDD: 80gb Deskstar IDE + external Seagate

I am trying to install Windows 7. My problem is that it won't recognize my HDD during installation.

I have an old IDE HDD which I'm using with an adapter for SATA. It's not working.

Currently I'm trying to update the BIOS without windows since it might help. I cannot get to the BIO-FLASHER by pressing F12. I've restarted and tried the other F keys as well. I can only get to the boot item menu with F9. I tested F keys on another computer to verify that the keyboard is working. I have placed the current H67BRC15.BST BIOS file at the root of a blank FAT32 USB stick and it's in a working USB port in the computer. This gives me two questions:

```
How do I update the BIOS without windows?

Why won't my IDE HDD work?
```

Other possibly useful information:

I have successfully ran Ubuntu 11.10 off of a USB stick, so everything seems to work.

The IDE to SATA adapter appears to work since my HDD shows up in the BIOS (I have the HDD set to master as well).

I have tried to get both Ubuntu and the Windows installer to read the HDD to no avail. I've tried using 15 pin and 16 pin master modes for the HDD as well.

In the BIOS I've tried setting the SATA settings to IDE mode, and to AHCI mode and tested those, with and without the extra options like SMART and Power Link Management. I've tried most of the SATA slots. With IDE mode the windows installer won't display the HDD (it says it needs drivers!). With AHCI mode it finds the HDD but says that I can't install to it, and I need to enable the controller in the BIOS, but both of them are enabled.

I cannot understand why the HDD can show up in the BIOS and not to the OS. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Installing Windows 7 from a USB stick using [wintoflash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)

Comment: Hello.
Are you trying to install Win 7 from a USB stick ?

Comment: Yes, I am, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the BIOStar [manual](http://206.108.48.60/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=511&tab=1) you can update the BIOS from within the BIOS (page 22 & 32).

It's a long shot, but make sure you haven't turned on any overclocking yet. I had this problem when I had set overclocking before I installed Windows 7. Once I reversed it, the install went as advertised.

It is also possible the HDD may be defective. Try connecting it to another PC to see if you can access it.

Comment: I've just finished going over both manuals on their website, and the one included on the cd again, and I can't find any useful information on bios updating outside of windows. Would you mind pasting the information? I think we may have different manual versions. 

Also, I haven't tampered with overclocking yet, but good guess. It's nice to know that someone experienced this and solved it.

Comment: Page 22 lead me to believe you can, but I missed the words "under Windows" on page 32. Sorry about that. I can't believe they don't have a BIOS flash utility that isn't windows based.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using the USB3 ports 
(blue ones usually) either to attempt to flash the bios, or to install Windows. Windows 7 installer doesn't have USB3 drivers