# Trying to install OS to new computer; Won't detect HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bios, sata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to install OS to new computer; Won't detect HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/372309/trying-to-install-os-to-new-computer-wont-detect-hdd)

Mobo: Biostar th67+

CPU: i3 2100

GPU: AMD 6850 (using integrated right now)

PSU: Antec 400 Watts

HDD: 80gb Deskstar IDE + external seagate

I am trying to install Windows 7. My problem is that it won't recognize my HDD during installation.

I have an old IDE HDD which I'm using with an adapter for SATA. It's not working.

Currently I'm trying to update the BIOS without windows since it might help. I cannot get to the BIO-FLASHER by pressing F12. I've restarted and tried the other F keys as well. I can only get to the boot item menu with F9. I tested F keys on another computer to verify that the keyboard is working. I have placed the current H67BRC15.BST BIOS file at the root of a blank FAT32 USB stick and it's in a working USB port in the computer. This gives me two questions:

1. How do I update the BIOS without windows?
2. Why won't my IDE HDD work?

Other possibly useful information:

I have successfully ran ubuntu 11.10 off of a USB stick, so everything seems to work.

The IDE to SATA adapter appears to work since my HDD shows up in the BIOS (I have the HDD set to master as well).

I have tried to get both Ubuntu and the Windows installer to read the HDD to no avail. I've tried using 15 pin and 16 pin master modes for the HDD as well.

In the BIOS I've tried setting the SATA settings to IDE mode, and to AHCI mode and tested those, with and without the extra options like SMART and Power Link Management. I've tried most of the SATA slots. With IDE mode the windows installer won't display the HDD (it says it needs drivers!). With AHCI mode it finds the HDD but says that I can't install to it, and I need to enable the controller in the BIOS, but both of them are enabled.

I cannot understand why the HDD can show up in the BIOS and not to the OS. Any help is appreciated! I didn't know where else to ask, and Ubuntu is the only OS that I can boot right now.

Comment: You should really look into upgrading your Hard Drive as it will be the bottle neck on your system. Even though the Sata port is capable of performing faster, the HDD interface is still IDE and limited to 100/133.

Answer (score 0):

I say install ubuntu on the drive, or run the live version and check if the drive is there, make sure the IDE are shorted to either cable select/master[I prefer master]
check this link out http://www.pchell.com/hardware/masterslaveorcableselect.shtml for help with selecting between CS=cable select M=Master

Comment: Yep, it's set to master. I'm going to try installing Ubuntu to the drive from another PC since it's system independent (and the usb install isn't detecting the drive). Good advice, I'll post back if it works.